# JSP with conditional checks is static or dynamic

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags, dispatcher

If I am going to include JSP if condition tag or any Conditional check tags will the JSP is static of dynamic. If I have a dispatcher configured for my webserver. Will the JSPs will run on each request or will the HTMLs that are rendered with the JSPs will be cached?

Comment: A JSP is just a servlet too. The code is called on every request. Partly caching of the written HTML can be left to the browser using an expiration.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the conditional tags are what make a page dynamic, because if it only is plain text will display the same thing over and over, but adding conditional statements make the page react to the user.

The JSP will be rendered on each request, the cashes are as simple HTML file in your browser's cache.